# Select unique rows after union query

Tags: mysql

Have this query:

```
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and titel like '%term%') 
UNION               
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and auther like '%term%')
```

However, there are duplicatie rows in result, I want only unique product_id - I tried group by product_id but this does not work.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the distinct after the union query, like this for example?

```
SELECT distinct(x.status) status,x.cb_ebook,x.product_id,x.titel,x.auther,x.image
FROM
(
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and titel like '%term%')
UNION
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and auther like '%term%')
) x
```

Comment: Hi thanks all for answers, I can not yet vote-up since I am new and have not yet minimum reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two queries. Just put all in the  `where` clause

```
select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image 
from oc_product 
where status 
and cb_ebook 
and (auther like '%term%' or titel like '%term%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ues

```
UNION DISTINCT
```

instead of

```
UNION
```

You can try this

```
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and titel like '%term%') 
UNION DISTINCT              
(select status, cb_ebook, product_id, titel, auther, image from oc_product where status and cb_ebook and auther like '%term%')
```